# Yandex Maps doesn't work on Genymotion and some devices

Tags: android, device, yandex-maps

I Implemented activity with

`ru.yandex.yandexmapkit.MapView`

When I launche this Activity on Asus zenfone or Samsung Note 3 it's OK!
But when I Launch on Genymotion Virtual Device it throw exception

`android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class ru.yandex.yandexmapkit.MapView`

And same problem on some other devices (nexus 2013)

How to Correct this Exception?

here is XML

```
<ru.yandex.yandexmapkit.MapView
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:apiKey="1234567890" />
```

here is exception

```
' 11-24 12:06:46.125 314-341/? E/Genymotion: Could not open /sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
    11-24 12:06:46.277 1008-1008/? D/OpenGLRenderer: TextureCache::get: create texture(0xb7e8d638): name, size, mSize = 143, 324, 179740
    11-24 12:06:46.329 1008-1008/? D/DrawerOnClickListener: drawer item with position 1 clicked
    11-24 12:06:46.329 123-197/? W/genymotion_audio: out_write() limiting sleep time 46802 to 39909
    11-24 12:06:46.381 1008-1008/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
    11-24 12:06:46.381 1008-1008/? W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa625b288)
    11-24 12:06:46.401 1008-1010/? D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 557K, 12% free 8893K/10055K, paused 13ms+1ms, total 18ms
    11-24 12:06:46.409 123-197/? W/genymotion_audio: out_write() limiting sleep time 58911 to 39909
    11-24 12:06:46.417 1008-1008/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    11-24 12:06:46.417 1008-1008/? E/AndroidRuntime: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class ru.yandex.yandexmapkit.MapView
    11-24 12:06:46.417 1008-1008/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
    11-24 12:06:46.417 1008-1008/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
    11-24 12:06:46.417 1008-1008/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
    11-24 12:06:46.417 1008-1008/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
    11-24 12:06:46.417 1008-1008/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
    11-24 12:06:46.417 1008-1008/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at kz.kazdream.shanyraq.fragment.MapFragment.onCreateView(MapFragment.java:69)
    11-24 12:06:46.417 1008-1008/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1962)
    11-24 12:06:46.417 1008-1008/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1026)
    11-24 12:06:46.417 1008-1008/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1207)
    11-24 12:06:46.417 1008-1008/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
    11-24 12:06:46.417 1008-1008/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1572)
    11-24 12:06:46.417 1008-1008/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:493)
    11-24 12:06:46.417 1008-1008/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
    11-24 12:06:46.417 1008-1008/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    11-24 12:06:46.417 1008-1008/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    11-24 12:06:46.417 1008-1008/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
    11-24 12:06:46.417 1008-1008/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    11-24 12:06:46.417 1008-1008/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    11-24 12:06:46.417 1008-1008/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
    11-24 12:06:46.417 1008-1008/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
    11-24 12:06:46.417 1008-1008/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    11-24 12:06:46.417 1008-1008/? E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    11-24 12:06:46.417 1008-1008/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
    11-24 12:06:46.417 1008-1008/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
    11-24 12:06:46.417 1008-1008/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
    11-24 12:06:46.417 1008-1008/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687) 
    11-24 12:06:46.417 1008-1008/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746) 
    11-24 12:06:46.417 1008-1008/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489) 
    11-24 12:06:46.417 1008-1008/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396) 
    11-24 12:06:46.417 1008-1008/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at kz.kazdream.shanyraq.fragment.MapFragment.onCreateView(MapFragment.java:69) 
    11-24 12:06:46.417 1008-1008/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1962) 
    11-24 12:06:46.417 1008-1008/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1026) 
    11-24 12:06:46.417 1008-1008/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1207) 
    11-24 12:06:46.417 1008-1008/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738) 
    11-24 12:06:46.417 1008-1008/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1572) 
    11-24 12:06:46.417 1008-1008/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:493) 
    11-24 12:06:46.417 1008-1008/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615) 
    11-24 12:06:46.417 1008-1008/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 
    11-24 12:06:46.417 1008-1008/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
    11-24 12:06:46.417 1008-1008/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 
    11-24 12:06:46.417 1008-1008/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
    11-24 12:06:46.417 1008-1008/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
    11-24 12:06:46.417 1008-1008/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786) 
    11-24 12:06:46.417 1008-1008/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
    11-24 12:06:46.417 1008-1008/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
    11-24 12:06:46.417 1008-1008/? E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load cache: findLibrary returned null
    11-24 12:06:46.417 1008-1008/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:365)
    11-24 12:06:46.417 1008-1008/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:535)
    11-24 12:06:46.417 1008-1008/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at ru.yandex.core.CoreApplication.initialize(Unknown Source)
    11-24 12:06:46.417 1008-1008/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at ru.yandex.core.CoreApplication.initOnce(Unknown Source)
    11-24 12:06:46.417 1008-1008/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at ru.yandex.yandexmapkit.MapSurfaceView.init(Unknown Source)
    11-24 12:06:46.417 1008-1008/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at ru.yandex.yandexmapkit.MapSurfaceView.<init>(Unknown Source)
    11-24 12:06:46.417 1008-1008/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at ru.yandex.yandexmapkit.MapView.<init>(Unknown Source)
    11-24 12:06:46.417 1008-1008/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
    11-24 12:06:46.417 1008-1008/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417) 
    11-24 12:06:46.417 1008-1008/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587) 
    11-24 12:06:46.417 1008-1008/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687) 
    11-24 12:06:46.417 1008-1008/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746) 
    11-24 12:06:46.417 1008-1008/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489) 
    11-24 12:06:46.417 1008-1008/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396) 
    11-24 12:06:46.417 1008-1008/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at kz.kazdream.shanyraq.fragment.MapFragment.onCreateView(MapFragment.java:69) 
    11-24 12:06:46.417 1008-1008/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1962) 
    11-24 12:06:46.417 1008-1008/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1026) 
    11-24 12:06:46.417 1008-1008/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1207) 
    11-24 12:06:46.417 1008-1008/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738) 
    11-24 12:06:46.417 1008-1008/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1572) 
    11-24 12:06:46.417 1008-1008/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:493) 
    11-24 12:06:46.417 1008-1008/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615) 
    11-24 12:06:46.417 1008-1008/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 
    11-24 12:06:46.417 1008-1008/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
    11-24 12:06:46.417 1008-1008/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 
    11-24 12:06:46.417 1008-1008/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
    11-24 12:06:46.417 1008-1008/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
    11-24 12:06:46.417 1008-1008/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786) 
    11-24 12:06:46.417 1008-1008/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
    11-24 12:06:46.417 1008-1008/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: It will be much easier for people to help you if you post the **entire** stack trace.

Comment: @CommonsWare Sorry! I really forgot it.

Comment: It appears to be having difficulty loading the NDK binaries (Linux `.so` files). You might check the documentation for both products (Yandex Maps and Genymotion) to see if there are any limitations on NDK CPU architectures that each supports. For example, Genymotion might only accept x86, and Yandex Maps might not ship x86.

Comment: @CommonsWare So, how can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yandex MapKit does not work on x86; to avoid this, x86 device/emulator should emulate ARM architecture.

Link: [Genymotion | Installing ARM Translation](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2528952).

Issue on Github: https://github.com/yandexmobile/yandexmapkit-android/issues/74

Comment: this Issue also solved here on Russian language  https://github.com/yandexmobile/yandexmapkit-android/issues/129